# How can I do simple validation of a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, drop-down-menu

I've made a 'question-answer form' in HTML and linked it with Javascript so that people could answer with a specific number. Here is the sample of my code:

HTML code:

```
<p>Question</p>
<p>1)"ans1"</p>
<p>2)"ans2"</p>
<p>3)"ans3"</p>
<p>4)"ans4"</p>
<form method="POST" name="CorrectForm" 
   onSubmit="checkCorrect(document.CorrectForm.numCorrect.value); return false;">

    <input type="text" name="numCorrect" id="numCorrect">
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var correctnumber = 1;
var errormessage = "blabla";

function checkTrue (numTrue){        
    if (numCorrect == correctNumber){  
         alert("Correct")
    }else{
        alert(errormessage);
    }
}
```

Now what I want is to let people choose an answer from a dropdown list. So I want the answers to be checked when the submit button is pressed.

So, HTML looks like

```
<p>Question</p>
<select>
    <option value="ans1">ans1</option>
    <option value="ans2">ans2</option>
    <option value="ans3">ans3</option>
    <option value="ans4">ans4</option>
</select>
```

So now I'm need of the JS part.

I apologize if this question has been asked a million times before, as I tried searching for a solution but didn't find one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: onChange="checkCorrect(this.value)"

Comment: set the name and id attributes of your select, and change the values of the options to numeric, eg: `<select name="numCorrect" id="numCorrect"... <option value="1">...`

Comment: You should change tags and title, they are misleading, the question is essentially about form validation in HTML e JS, no jQuery is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a function that validates just the input number, you can create a function that validates the full form. See this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Validation test</title>

<script>
var rightAnswer = 3;

function checkAnswer(form) {
    if (parseInt(form.elements["answer"].value) == rightAnswer) {
        alert("Correct");
    } else {
        alert("Wrong");
    }
    return false;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" onsubmit="checkAnswer(this); return false;">
    <p>Question:</p>
    <select name="answer">
        <option value="1">ans1</option>
        <option value="2">ans2</option>
        <option value="3">ans3</option>
        <option value="4">ans4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Some remarks:

- In the code for the event `onsubmit=""`, you can use the keywork `this` to refer to the form itself, and pass it to the `checkAnswer()` function.
- When you have the variable `form` that points to your HTML form, you can retrieve its fields through `form.elements["NAME"]`, where `NAME` matches the attribute `name=""` in the HTML tag. This works for all controls,  `select`, `button`, `input`, with the exception of `<input type="image">`.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.elements) about this, it contains good reference about every object in the HTML DOM, in particular [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

- You might still need to convert the `value` to an integer to be able to compare it to your right answer, that's the reason for `parseInt`.
- This approach can be generalized: what you want to do is equivalent to **form validation**, you can find online plenty of libraries and tutorials that explain in detail how to do it; there are also many answers, if you know what to look for.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understood everything you typed (except parseInt that's new for me) and I applied it to my original script, but it won't seem to work. When I try to submit an answer it does not respond. I copied and pasted your answer carefully, all I did was change the "rightAnswer" into 1. And I checked for mistakes but didn't find any. So what can I do now?

Comment: @Kirito I added the full HTML code to the answer, works in Firefox 30, Chrome 35, Safari 7.0.5.

Comment: Okay I figured it out. It was just interacting with some other codes that were messing it up.

Thanks again.